# Why do all my print statements start with "@" in VSCode's Debug Console?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, logging, cmake, formatting

Using C++ with the CMake Tools extensions for VSCode... when I debug my program it writes to VSCode's Debug Console but every line starts with "@" and shows the newlines at the end:

```cpp
std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Another line..." << std::endl;
```

```
@"Hello, World!\r\n"
@"Another line...\r\n"
```

How do I configure VSCode and/or the cmake extension to print 'normally'?

Comment: Which cmake generator do you use? Using Visual Studio and make + g++ generators I haven't encountered this behaviour. There could be some cmake configuration options VS Code applies without your knowlege, but the behaviour you describe would be pretty strange for any compiler. Try running the executable built by VS Code from a terminal outside of VS Code and check, if the behoviour is the same. If it's not, there are probably some console settings that result in this kind of output.

Comment: I'm using the Xcode generator on macOS. Running the same executable in Terminal produces the expected output (with no extra characters).